# How to feed batch tensor into single-value tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to fine-tune [MobileNet_v1_1.0_224](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md).

The problem I'm facing is input:0 has a shape [1,224,224,3]. I'd like to feed it a batch of arbitrary size, e.g. [100,224,224,3]. The code I'm playing with is [Tensorflow for poets](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2), [retrain.py](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py) to be exact.

Here is what is printed from input:0 tensor:

```
image_buffer_input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
print (image_buffer_input)
> Tensor("input:0", shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Trying to feed a batch of 100 raises an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(1, 224, 224, 3)'
```

Is there a way to get around it?

P.S.

Here is how I try to train:

```
  sess.run(train_step,
        feed_dict={image_buffer_input: train_image_buffers,
                   ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})
```

Comment: Do you mean the batch size is hardcoded to 1? It seems very strange.

Comment: Updated issue description.